# scanf inside an If statement on a do while loop messes up the inputs

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, do-while

When the input is a negative integer, the program should ask if you want to reset.

It worked fine when I test it with a negative integer. But when I try a positive integer, it doesn't work (I have to enter stuff twice).

```
int main(void) {
    int user_input;
    char check;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        if (user_input < 0)
            printf("Error. Do you want to continue using the program? y/n: ");
            scanf(" %c", &check);

    } while (check == 'y');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me draw your attention to MISRA C:2012 Rule 15.6... you've demonstrated WHY that Rule is a good idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `scanf` should be inside brackets, otherwise it is not part of the if statement. Unlike languages like Python, indendation does not matter.

Your code *always* executes `scanf(" %c", &check)`, regardless of the user input.

```c
int main(void) {
    int user_input;
    char check;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        if (user_input < 0) {
            printf("Error. Do you want to continue using the program? y/n: ");
            scanf(" %c", &check);
        }

    } while (check == 'y');

  return 0;
}
```

The following blocks are identical:

```c
if (something)
    statementA;
    statementB;
```

```c
if (something)
    statementA;
statementB;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant believe I missed the brackets. I got so used from using Python.